# python : Mode of a List

Tags: python

can you help me in this python problem?

Write a Python function `all_modes(l)` that takes a nonempty
list `l` and returns a pair with a set of all its
modes and their frequency:

So, here is my code:

```
def all_modes(l):
    d = {}
    for c in l:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 1
        else:
            d[c] = d[c] + 1 
    return ({c},d[c])
```

And here are some runs of it, unfortunately this output is wrong:

```
>>> all_modes([5, 6, 7, 5]) 
({5}, 2)

>>> all_modes([5])
({5}, 1)

>>> all_modes([5, 6, 7, 5, 6])
({5, 6}, 2)

>>> all_modes([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
({8, 9, 5, 6, 7}, 1)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: One thing you can fix: `d` is a dict and it doesn't have `append`. You need to process the dict *after* it's completely built.

Comment: what are test cases : what you want or what you have ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to only return values whose occurence count is maximized (the crux of mode).  Something like this, maybe?

```
from collections import defaultdict

def modes(l):
  d = defaultdict(int)
  for num in l:
    d[num] += 1
  m = max(d.values())
  return {k for k, v in d.items() if v == m}, m
```

Answer (score 2):

You've returned the wrong stuff.  When you hit your **return** statement, **c** is simply the last item in the list.  You've returned that and its count.

You have to go back to find the maximum value in the dictionary:

```
count_max = max([v for v in d.itervalues()])
```

and then find all of the list values that have that count:

```
mode_list = [k for k,v in d.iteritems() if v == count_max]
```

The program is now:

```
def all_modes(l):
    d = {}
    for c in l:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 1
        else:
            d[c] = d[c] + 1

    count_max = max([v for v in d.itervalues()])
    mode_list = [k for k,v in d.iteritems() if v == count_max]

    return (mode_list, count_max)

print all_modes([5, 6, 7, 5])
print all_modes([5])
print all_modes([5, 6, 7, 5, 6])
print all_modes([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Output:

```
([5], 2)
([5], 1)
([5, 6], 2)
([8, 9, 5, 6, 7], 1)
```

Is this what you needed?

Comment: That's the more accessible version: note that you can easily build the original dictionary with the **collections.Counter** subclass.